# How can I troubleshoot whether an unconfirmed transaction that seems stuck is a problem on my end or just from high volume on mempool?

Tags: transaction-fees, electrum, unconfirmed-transactions

Never had transaction hang unconfirmed like this before. Granted its only been a few hours but it's not like I skimped on fees either. I always choose the default electrum fee, but when it got stuck I doubled it using RBF to increase the fee.

But it's still stuck!

How can I check whether I'm really in the queue being ignored because people are paying higher fees or if there's something wrong I'm doing on my end?

Regenerating my wallet in electrum at least restored my pre-send balance. So at least I can see my coin even if there's no movement on this transaction that I'd love to either cancel out of or see confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check whether I'm really in the queue being ignored because people are paying higher fees or if there's something wrong I'm doing on my end?

What was the **fee rate** used for the transaction?

https://mempool.observer

Example: I will have to use fee rate more than 100 sat/vbyte for a quick confirmation right now

Answer (score 0):

A good way to check whether your transaction has been seen by nodes in the bitcoin network is to check on a public blockchain explorer such as [Blockstream](https://blockstream.info). Simply look up the transaction by the transaction ID, or look up the bitcoin address you spent from/sent bitcoin to.